# What am I doing with with this flickr api query?

Tags: api, rpc, flickr

I'm new to the flickr API, and I assumed fetching photos from a given photoset was simply a case of making a rest request with an api key and user listed, like so:

```
    $ curl http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getList&api_key=249f544ccfec879bc602f23c7441047c&user_id=36940190@N04&format=json
```

But when I try this, I get the following response:

```
    [1] 2193
    [2] 2194
    [3] 2195
    [2]-  Done                    api_key=249f544ccfec879bc602f23c7441047c
    ~$ <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <rsp stat="fail">
        <err code="100" msg="Invalid API Key (Key not found)" />
    </rsp>
```

This API key is the one assigned to me at `http://www.flickr.com/services/api/keys/` when I registered my account, so I'm confused about why I'm getting this message.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just for the record: the Flickr API is not RESTful :)

Comment: Retagged. It's pure RPC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must quote the & characters in your query. Put single quotation marks around the complete URL.